# Android soundpool onTouch not working

Tags: java, android, touch-event, soundpool

I'm having a strange issue playing a sound effect when the user touches the screen. I'm really not sure where to go with this. I have a class named sing and a method called sound() that plays the sound effect. In the onCreate() method, the code works fine, but in the onTouch() method, it doesnt.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
TextView textview;
Sing sing;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("Test");
    setContentView(textview);
    sing = new Sing();
    sing.create();
    sing.sound("sound.ogg");//just to test, works fine
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        sing.sound("sound.ogg"); //doesnt work
    } 
    return true;
}
```

The first call to sing.sound() in onCreate() works fine, but the subsequent call in onTouch() doesn't seem to be doing anything. This test class extends activity and implements onTouch, i've imported onTouch, and beyond that I really dont know what the error could be. I would post the sing class but it's kind of a lot of code. 
Any help anyone can give would be EXTREMELY appreciated. I've been struggling with this for an embarrassingly long time today, I'm not very good with android yet. Thanks in advance.

--edit
Here is the entire activity:

```
package com.test.ch4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SoundPoolTest extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
TextView textview;
Sing sing;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setTextSize(40);
    textview.setText("Test");
    setContentView(textview);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        sing = new Sing();
        sing.create();
        sing.sound("sound.ogg");
    } 
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure onTouch() is firing? Put Log.d("ontouch","fired"); in the onTouch method and check to see if it comes up on your logcat

Comment: can you put up your whole activity, i think you implemented your onTouch() incorrectly

Comment: I put up the rest of the activity. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: i posted answer that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
setContentView(textview);
```

put

```
textview.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

then before your onTouch() method put @Override like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        sing = new Sing();
        sing.create();
        sing.sound("sound.ogg");
    } 
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: AH! such a simple mistake. Thank you!

Comment: hey no problem remember what i commented about Log.d() up there it really comes in handy while your testing